# PHP Regex to match words with dash right infront and save to array?

Tags: php, regex

i'm wondering what kind of regex I could use to essentially extract all the words that have a dash infront of them in a given string. I'm going to be using it to allow users to omit certain words from the search results of my website.

For example, say I have

```
$str = "this is a search -test1 -test2";
```

I'm trying to have it save `"test1"` and `"test2"` to an array because they have a dash right infront.

Could anyone help me out

Comment: What comes after the dash?

Comment: Can you define 'word' a bit more clearly. Typically the definition doesn't include numbers but your test cases do. What about underscores and other symbols?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, my definition of word is any letters / numbers /  symbols ending when a space is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following pattern `/\-(\w+)/`. Example:

```
$string = 'this is a search -test1 -test2';
$pattern = '/\-(\w+)/';
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    $result = $matches[1];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "test1"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "test2"
}
```

Explanation:

```
/.../ delimiter chars

\-    a dash (must be escaped as it has a special meaning in the regex language

(...) special capture group. stores the content between them in $matches[1]

\w+   At least one ore more word characters
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed and the clear explanation really helped :)

Comment: np :) I hope *word* character is ok for you. Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.escape.php).. If not, the pattern could be modified to match until a space is reached

Answer (score 2):

this do the job:

```
<pre><?php    
$string = 'Phileas Fog, Passe-Partout -time -day -@StrAn-_gE+*$Word²²²';
preg_match_all('~ -\K\S++~', $string, $results);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I got `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` Where have you tested it?

Comment: @hek2mgl: because the pattern don't have any capture group

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Didn't checked this... Btw change `print_r($result)` to `$results` ;)